# Cancelling useEffect's Async with TypeScript, the correct way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-effect

I have this simple example that's giving me grief:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(...).then(...).catch(...)

}, [props.foo])
```

> warning: can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component

Done some research and [this one](https://juliangaramendy.dev/use-promise-subscription/) is more understandable. TypeScript seems not to like that approach as `useEffect` should return a void.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let isSubscribed = true

  axios.get(...).then(...).catch(...)

  return () => (isSubscribed = false)

}, [props.foo])
```

**TypeScript:**

```js
/**
     * Accepts a function that contains imperative, possibly effectful code.
     *
     * @param effect Imperative function that can return a cleanup function
     * @param deps If present, effect will only activate if the values in the list change.
     *
     * @version 16.8.0
     * @see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect
     */
    function useEffect(effect: EffectCallback, deps?: DependencyList): void;
```

How to implement an `isSubscribed` in my `useEffect` with TS?

Thanks.

Comment: I this reddit post solves it with curly braces: `{isSubscribed = false}` https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/blhj2b/how_do_i_cancelignore_previously_running_promises/

Answer (score 4):

`useEffect` itself returns `void`, but the function provided to `useEffect` is typed as `EffectCallback`. This is definied as:

```
// NOTE: callbacks are _only_ allowed to return either void, or a destructor.
// The destructor is itself only allowed to return void.
type EffectCallback = () => (void | (() => void | undefined));
```

[Source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1febfb278c9f230ba6d3fc885986f7284fb8c6d6/types/react/index.d.ts#L858)

This means your effect callback can actually return a function, which has to return `void` or `undefined`.

Now you can solve your issue to avoid calling `setState` with the `isSubscribed` variable. But another (maybe better) way is to outright cancel the request.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
  const source = CancelToken.source();

  axios.get('...', { cancelToken: source.token }).then(/**/).catch(e => {
    if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
      console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
    } else {/* handle error */}
  });

  return () => source.cancel();
}, [props.foo])
```

This is also documented in the [README](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/521444513969a08ec5ef943c41ba0812845ed4f9/README.md#cancellation).

The problem with your current code is, that your destructor function returns the boolean `isSubscribed`. Instead of returning it, just put the assignment into a function body:

```
return () => {
  isSubscribed = false;
}
```